# Why are my bootstrap btn-inverted buttons showing up as grey instead of a black gradient?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am using angular, bootstrap and jquery to populate buttons using json. However when i set the styling to style it like this:

[image: inverted bootstrap button]

it shows up like this:

[image: faulty inverted bootstrap button]

so how can i get bootstrap to render the buttons correctly?

Stackoverflow code preview isn't working.
Plunk for project is here:
http://plnkr.co/edit/FmK38oyDRZzWOTstoaEo

```js
var bridgeCreek = angular.module('bridgeCreek', []);

bridgeCreek.controller('MyController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get('http://www.zaithe.com/demos/bridgeCreek/js/json/navigation.json').success(function(data) {
    $scope.navigation = data;
  });
}]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="bridgeCreek">
  <head>
      <link data-require="bootstrap@*" data-semver="3.3.1" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  </head>
  <body ng-controller="MyController">
      <ul class="nav navbar-right navbar-nav">
          <li ng-repeat="item in navigation">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-inverse btn-sm">
                  <span ng-class="item.glyph" aria-hidden="true"></span> {{item.text}}
              </button>
          </li>
  
      </ul>
      <script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="2.1.3" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
      
      <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.4.0-beta.5" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0-beta.5/angular.js"></script>
      <script src="script.js"></script>
      <script data-require="bootstrap@*" data-semver="3.3.1" src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had a look at the styles associated with your button elements and there is no style for btn-inverse. Which means you are missing the css files you need.

I just checked the bootstrap docs and it looks like btn-inverse has been discontinued so that is probably why you are missing the css :-(

This text is from their docs:

**Changes to Button Color Classes**

Add btn-default to btn elements with no other color. Replace btn-inverse with btn-default since inverse has been removed from Bootstrap 3.

Comment: Thank you, I consider this a solution to this question!

Comment: @DerekRhode if this answer helped you, please consider [accepting it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) (clicking on the big green tick below the vote buttons).